# Does adding all the roles in to a group and creating a sharing rule with read only with the same group make the owner permission read only?

Tags: sharing-rule, roles, role-hierarchy

I have around 20 roles in the same level, like this:

```
(not showing the parents of a and b)
   |        |   
   a        b       (level x)
   |        |   
------  ---------
|    |  |   |   |
a1, a2  b1, b2, b3  (level y)
```

where `a1, a2, b1, b2, b3` are on the same level. Now I want to share records create by a role in level y with all other roles in the same level y but in read only mode.

What I did was:

1. I created a public group and put all the roles in the level y in the group and named it level y group.
2. I created a sharing rule for the lead object where I put: **Owned by members of** Group: level y group and **Share with** Group: level y group.

My question is will this work? For example if a user associated with role a1 created a lead and using the sharing rule I am sharing with all the members of level y which also includes myself in read only mode. The owner a1 will also be in read only mode or can a1 still edit while others can only read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing is always cumulative, so you cannot reduce access to a record via a sharing rule. The owner of the record will still have Ownership permission (Full Access).

Answer (score 1):

If someone of role a1 creates a lead then he/she can still edit the record of that lead.